# Crystal model parameters in spice

Tags: crystal, spice, modeling

I have these nice piezo transducers to characterize (of course the datasheet is incomplete) and make a spice model for oscillator design purposes. Now, Rhea and the other people say "hook it up to a VNA and it will give the parameters", but, of course, I'm poor. So I used the bode plot app inside of the scope. Generator and channel 1 to one pin of the transducer, channel 2 to the other pins, grounds all together.

This should me a poor man S21 plot with a drive impedance of 50 ohms (the generator) and a load of 10meg||12pF (the probe load). It does, in fact, work and the result is sensible. Scope does Ch2/Ch1 so load on the source is compensated.

[image: Transmission plot]

The phase in resonance is suspicious but a scope is not the best thing to measure small phase deviations, I'm ok with that.
Going to model the primary resonance pair: Fs=1.85MHz, Fp=1.93MHz; Q is going to be quite low, but PZT is notorious for that.

First thing strange: from spec it should be Fs=1.7MHz±70kHz.

Measured one is too high. First idea: is the probe loading the transducer and pulling it? I assume that the datasheet is measured on a calibrate 50 ohm resistive system. Fine with that.
As for the model the formulas are quite everywhere, I used these http://www.sark110.com/application-notes/equivalent-circuit-determination-of-quartz-crystals (which match with the Rhea ones).
Co is specced as 1.7nF; Rs is, well, they say 'less than 1.5 ohms'. 1.4 matches well on amplitude and phase for the simulation.

So I did this spice fixture. It should match decently what I did. Generator, two probes, resonator. Checked against the formulas at
https://www.pspice.com/resources/application-notes/modelling-quartz-crystals and both fs and fs match reasonably.

[image: Spice Fixture for transmission response]

The AC sweep however… well, doesn't match:
[image: AC trasmission response]

The overall shape is fine. Considering the input loading (green trace) the amplitude matches (the plot *doesn't* have Vout/Vin) and phase drops a little too much but is still plausible. fs and fp are completely wrong (1.925MHz and 1.93MHz).

What is happening here? Is this a probe pull issue? As in:

- The original transducer was 1.7MHz and was pulled to 1.85MHz
- I designed a model for the 1.85MHz and the simulated probes pulled the simulator resonator to 1.925MHz.

However, if this is the case, how could I calibrate out the probe load? I know from the datasheet that the main fs is 1.7MHz, but, for example, how could I find the real frequency for the radial mode resonance at about 150kHz (the leftmost one)?

Comment: The link for the quartz crystal isn't to a specific quartz crystal so I have no idea how you got the equivalent values in your simulation. There's too much here. I can help but concentrate on one thing such as your modelled crystal. Your real measurements are flawed in that your phase angle does not shift anything like 180 degrees over the series/parallel resonance (i.e. you should be measuring Z). Simplify, simplify and simplify to something really objective. One step at a time if you want answers. [This web page](http://www.stades.co.uk/XTAL%20Oscillator/XTAL%20Oscillator.html) might help.

Comment: Your title and tag say "SPICE", yet your questions are about the measurement and the methodology. Which one is it?

Comment: Is your goal to make it work? make it match the specs? Get a simulation to match the test? Pick 1

Comment: OK, first of all is not a quartz but a ceramic transducer. The goal is to have a plausible model to put in spice and design an oscillator. I'm suspicious of the measurements, too (probably the probes load the resonator). The spice tag is because I did measurements and the spice model didn't match

Comment: Also, to be clear: I did a transmit measurement, *not* an impedance one. Most of the literature does the modeling with S-parameters and this is the most similar thing I can do.